# How can I view repository-side changes before checking out?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

We're in the process of migrating a big, old codebase from StarTeam to SVN.  Everything's going really smoothly, except that a lot of people are missing one of StarTeam's features.

In StarTeam, it can query the repository and display a list for you of all files by status.  It shows all unchanged files, all files that you've changed, all files that have been changed in the repository that you haven't checked out, all files that are new in the repository that you haven't checked out, all files that have changed on both sides and will require a merge, and all files that you have and the repository doesn't.

It's easy enough to use TortoiseSVN to see changes at your end, but how do you see what changes have happened in the repository without actually running SVN Update and downloading them?

Answer (score 4):

Right click directory -> TortoiseSVN menu -> check for modifications.

This will show your local changes, the remote server changes (as compared to your files) and all property modifications, too.

There are more details [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html) about half way down the page.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for

```
svn status -u
```

Answer (score 2):

And for the record, here is the CLI version:

```
svn diff -r BASE:HEAD
```

Comment: That outputs all the actual line-level diffs, rather than just showing a list of changed files.

Comment: Joe White: `svn diff -r BASE:HEAD | diffstat`